# c++ read struct data by bytes

Tags: c++, struct

I use Visual Studio Micro C++ to program Arduino Mega1280 AVR.

I keep all my mixed types config parameters in a struct that is persisted in the 4096 Bytes EEPROM (in addition to other information saved in the EEPROM).

For every new program upload, I wish to check the new config against the EEPROM saved config, which I do byte by byte, updating only EEPROM bytes that differ.

My problem is that while the code compiles OK, (no errors/warnings) I do not get what I expect, and when reading the struct by bytes, I only get part of the expected info. I need help to make it work properly. Thanks.

Here is my simplified code:

```
#include <avr\eeprom.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <Arduino.h>    

char configVersion[5] = "VS41";
unsigned int deviceID = 0xF0F0;
char deviceRev[5] = "ABCD";
char revDate[11] = "09-08-2014";
unsigned int dataArraySize = 150;

struct defineConfigs {  
    char configVersion[5];        
    unsigned int deviceID;        
    char deviceRev[5];            
    char revDate[11];              
    unsigned int dataArraySize;     
    byte mode;                  
    byte refpage;                   
    byte tolerance;             
    byte externalTrigger;           
    byte laserEnable;               
}
configData=
{
    {configVersion[5]},
    deviceID,
    {deviceRev[5]},
    {revDate[11]},
    dataArraySize,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    0,
    0
};

unsigned int configBaseAddress=3840; //0x0F00 

void Setup()
{
    loadConfig(configBaseAddress);
}

void loadConfig(int configAddress)    //EA
{
    int s;
    for ( s=0; s<sizeof(configData); s++) {

//  Serial.println(*((char*)(&configData) + s),HEX); //Serial.print(","); //for testing

        if (*((char*)(&configData) + s) == EEPROM.read(configAddress + s)) {
        } else {
            EEPROM.write(configAddress + s, *((byte*)(&configData) + s));
            Serial.println(EEPROM.read(configAddress + s),HEX);  
            //read back for testing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After further investigation, by printing the struct itself, I came to the conclusion that the problem is probably with the struct rather than the EEPROM saving.
I still need help to resolve.

Comment: Thank Quest.
Casting to Char rather than Char* generates 2 errors:
error: cast from 'defineConfigs*' to 'char' loses precision
error: invalid type argument of 'unary *'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization of configData use uninitialized data

```
{configVersion[5]}
```

point on the first character after the array configVersion[0 ... 4]. This is not as you expect the litteral string "VS41".
You could check this printing configData.configVersion :

```
printf("%s\n", configData.configVersion);
```

Try to modify configData initialization like this :

```
struct defineConfigs {
    char configVersion[5];
    unsigned int deviceID;
    char deviceRev[5];
    char revDate[11];
    unsigned int dataArraySize;
    byte mode;
    byte refpage;
    byte tolerance;
    byte externalTrigger;
    byte laserEnable;
} configData = {
    "VS41",
    deviceID,
    "ABCD",
    "09-08-2014",
    dataArraySize,
    1,
    2,
    0,
    0,
    0
};
```

Comment: How do I reward you in this forum??(you deserve one!)